# Fix Windows Server 2022 custom toolbar size when taskbar locked

Tags: taskbar, toolbar, windows-server-2022, desktop-toolbar

10 years later, are there any solutions to the problem with Windows Custom Toolbar changing size when locking Taskbar?

After I add a custom toolbar and move it all the way to the left, upon locking the taskbar, this happens:
[image: custom toolbar]

There is a bit of an icon in the right part of the toolbar's text. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally stumbled on a workaround:

1. **Create the toolbar starting from an empty folder.**
2. Position it, lock the taskbar. No icon shows.
3. Afterwards, add files and subfolders to your empty folder.

Thanks for nothing, Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to first uncheck *show text* & *show title* (after right clicking on your toolbar), then drag it to the desired position and make it as small as possible, finally check *show title* again and lock the taskbar.